# An example of a ring without identity that does not contain any maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

> I'm trying to find an example of a ring without identity that does not contain any maximal ideal.

Help me some hints.

Comment: Since you don't insist that there is an identity, just take an abelian group and define all products to be 0. This is a ring without identity and any subgroup is an ideal. So an abelian group that contains no maximal proper subgroup would be an example.

Comment: Continuing with KCd's remark, consider the abelian group $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I would try to reproduce the properties of a field. What happens if you have ax=c always having a solution? If this doesn't imply identity then we have only trivial ideals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take an abelian group without maximal subgroups, like $(\Bbb Q,+)$, and the zero multiplication, that is, $xy=0$ for any $x,y$.

Comment: I've posted this trivial example in order to prevent future possible *trivial* questions on this theme.

Answer (score 3):

Another example can be found in here http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/NoMaxIdeals.pdf